# htaccess redirect subdomain into folder that has similiar name with subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I did many way to do this, but always getting 404 error.

I want to redirect subdomain

```
[username].domain.com/
```

to

```
domain.com/user/[username]/index.php
```

and the url on browser address is not changed still

```
[username].domain.com/
```

[username] is dynamic according to registered user in my site.

my last trial httaccess setting is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ ^.domain.com/user%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

Note: I did set my DNS wildcard `*.domain.com`

Thanks in advance,

Nanang K

============================================================

**SOLVED**

I had to create 3 htaccess files.

1. in root directory (redirect to user)

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.domain.com
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /user/$1 [NC,L]
> ```

2. in user directory (redirect to username_folder)

> ```
> Options +FollowSymLinks
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ])$ user/$1/index.php
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.domain.com
> RewriteRule (.*) user/%1/index.php
> ```

3. in username_folder directory (rewrite the url into original url)

> ```
> Options +FollowSymLinks
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ])$ index.php?siteName=$1
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.domain.com
> RewriteRule (.*) index.php?siteName=%1
> ```

now, when user access `robert.domain.com`, he will get the content from `domain.com/user/robert/index.php`. And the url browser still `robert.domain.com`

hope helps someone who get similiar problem.

Comment: I think you should try more it will solve your issue with one htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Can you please try this :-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /users/$1 [L,NC]
```

It may use helpful.

Comment: it give me an error.

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this, try it out.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[username].domain.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com\/users\/" [R=301,L]
```

hope this helps!

Comment: this also gave me an error 404. may be because the user folder is in one location with my laravel installation.